# Cannot send message to content script properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm so close to finishing my Chrome extension. I have one or two things to do. One of them is sending a message from the content script to the background script. I wrote the following, but it doesn't quite what I want.

*content.js*

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0,len=a.length;i<len;i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
    var linkTitle = this.getAttribute('title').trim();
    var linkUrl = this.getAttribute('href');
    if ((linkTitle != null) && (linkTitle.length > 0)) {
      chrome.extension.sendMessage({action:'bookmarkLink', 'title':linkTitle, 'url': linkUrl}, function(msg) {
        alert('Messages sent: '+action+' and '+linkTitle+' also '+linkUrl);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({'title': 'Add to mySU bookmarks', 'contexts': ['link'], 'onclick': mySUBookmarkLink});

function mySUBookmarkLink(info, tab) {
  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.action == 'bookmarkLink') {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'title': msg.linkTitle, 'url': msg.linkUrl}, function(msg) {
        alert('Saved '+msg.linkTitle+' to bookmarks');
      });
    } 
  });
};
```

My problems are:

1. In the first code block, it alerts **Saved *undefined* to bookmarks** as soon as I right click on the link, while as I understand it should only send a message on right click and the second code block should alert **Saved  to bookmarks** when I click on the context menu. What am I missing or doing wrong?
2. I may not have used parameters correctly (I am fairly new to extension development and Javascript in general). Do the above look okay?

Thank you in advance,

K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's  JSON-serializable messaging, where first pair is for recognition, and then followed by pairs of
**key: value**.
You pull the value from received message by calling it's key.

is should be:

```
alert('Saved '+msg.title+' to bookmarks');
```

or even better:

```
function mySUBookmarkLink(info, tab) {
  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.action == 'bookmarkLink') {
      var receivedValue = msg.title; //pull it out first, for better overview
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'title': msg.title, 'url': msg.url}, function(msg) {
        alert('Saved '+receivedValue+' to bookmarks');
      });
    } 
  });
};
```

Comment: There is no `chrome.extension.onMessage`

Comment: yes, there is.
Even if those methods are deprecated, they are still usable. I just tested it in latest Canary.  
His problem is not chrome.runtime >> chrome.extension, but wrong syntax.  
Pls, don't down vote my answer just because you didn't get the problem :)

Comment: granted ... It's amazing how much Chrome developers messed around with the API over time. There is `chrome.extension.sendMessage` (not even mentioned in the API docs any more), `chrome.extension.sendRequest` (marked as deprecated in the API docs) and finally `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` which is currently the *preferred* way. Let's see what comes up next

Comment: still ... I think you should replace `msg.linkTitle` with `msg.title` and `msg.linkUrl` with `msg.url` because that's how the object is defined which has been sent

Comment: yes, overlooked that...I've just copied his code and altered alert, didn't realized that chrome.storage.sync.set is also wrong... but OP would probably get it from description :)...about API mess, my favorite is chrome.app.window.... tons of bounds (dimensions)+deprecated+bugged....

Comment: Uhm. I should have known that it won't work the first time. Maybe I am missing something? Replaced `extension` with `runtime`. content.js looks like http://jsfiddle.net/kartagis/E27SE/ and background.js like http://jsfiddle.net/kartagis/v2Uy6/

Comment: Hm, I tried again, and got this error/warning in the console: `Uncaught Error: Error connecting to extension gliaflgiiejkmiaehfmogfcndhehdmdo` My extension's ID used to be  ekblboljfpcmipbglbonbjicgehegdfa (I have no clue how it changed otra if this is even possible. Maybe I got this message because of the ID change. Also, I got a bug report when I traced down the message and it is http://crbug.com/168263.

Comment: did you reload the page?...content script (in page) is not updated if you just changed code and reloaded the extension.

Comment: I now reverted back to `extension`, it saves properly (verified in the file system), but doesn't alert anything.

Comment: your code is probably messed somewhere else. Your initial bug was wrong syntax, difference between extension<->runtime is not important right now.

Comment: your code is gonna make listener for context menu on link. And when user right click link, it's gonna send msg to background....BUT, background listener will be available only when user click context menu item!!!...kinda pointless in sending msg from content script..

Comment: So, I should listen on clicking the menu, am I right? Also, I am not getting the error `Uncaught Error: Error connecting to extension gliaflgiiejkmiaehfmogfcndhehdmdo` because (I think) the extension as I use at home and at work has somehow different ID's. Is this even possible?

Comment: yes, ext. will have different ID.
As far as I understand, you want to create extension in which when user click on the link, extension will create context menu item for saving that link without visiting page???... 
if that is the true, you don't need content script at all (I presume you wanted to fetch the data -title- and url that way). Here is Opera dev page for chrome.contextMenus, Chrome is 404
http://dev.opera.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData

onClickData is your info in mySUBookmarkLink.
See what you can fetch that way... 
var URL=info.linkUrl
not sure about link title

Answer (score 2):

It's `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` rather than `chrome.extension`.

There used to be `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and `chrome.extension.onRequest` which have been deprecated in favor of the `chrome.runtime` API methods mentioned above.

See [Chrome Extensions - Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)